# Why does .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider throw a "Safe handle has been closed" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, security, rsa

The following method is used to verify data against a public key using "SHA1". The first time the method is called is works correctly. However, when the method is called the second and subsequent times the following line

```
isVerified = RSA.VerifyData(tokenData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(hashType), signature);
```

causes this exception

```
{"Safe handle has been closed"} System.Exception {System.ObjectDisposedException}
```

Thoughts on what I might be doing incorrectly?

```
internal static bool VerifyTokenData(byte[] tokenData, byte[] signature, string hashType)
{
  try
  {
    bool isVerified = false;

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)CompanyAuthentication.publicKey)
    {
      isVerified = RSA.VerifyData(tokenData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(hashType), signature);
    }

    return isVerified;
  }
  catch (CryptographicException cryptoExc)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception verifying token data", cryptoExc);
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception verifying token data", exc);
  }
}
```

The public key used is loaded into a class variable using

```
internal static void LoadKeys()
{
  try
  {
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
    lock (CompanyAuthentication.thisLock)
    {
      certificate.Import(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["companyKeyFilePath"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["companyKeyFilePassword"].ToString(), X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
      CompanyAuthentication.publicKey = certificate.PublicKey.Key;
      CompanyAuthentication.privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
    }
  }
  catch (CryptographicException cryptoExc)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception creating public/private keys", cryptoExc);
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Exception creating public/private keys", exc);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Here's the revised code that functions properly. It loads the key file each time rather than once in the class constructor.

```
    SalesNetAuthentication.LoadKeys();
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)SalesNetAuthentication.publicKey)
    {
      isVerified = RSA.VerifyData(tokenData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(hashType), signature);
    }
```

Comment: It is like you drive a car and you park it against a telephone pole to end your trip.  If you bought the car then nobody cares too much about that.  If you borrowed it from your friend then he's going to say something.

Comment: Both answers below pointed to the problem being related to the .Dispose() method being called inside the using{} block. This MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) indicates in the Important Note that a using{} block should be used w/ RSACryptoServiceProvider. Therefore, I experimented and found that if the key file is loaded each time the RSACryptoServiceProvider is invoked then the using{} statement works properly (see Edit in question).

Answer (score 4):

Since you have `using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = ...` it's disposing of the object when the `using` scope ends.

The solution would be to remove the `using` so the object can be used on subsequent attempts, or recreate the object every time it needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're reusing the CompanyAuthentication.publicKey, even though you've disposed of it the first time you call (wrapping it in a using block causes the `.Dispose()` method to be called on it).

I don't think you want to be disposing of this object if you intend to keep using it.  Since this appears to be a static variable, you probably don't want to dispose it until you shutdown your app.